# SQL Joins . One to many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables as below

```
Table 1
-----------------------------------
UserID   | UserName | Age | Salary
-----------------------------------
1        | foo      | 22  | 33000       
-----------------------------------
```

```
Table 2
------------------------------------------------
UserID   | Age      | Salary     | CreatedDate
------------------------------------------------
1        | NULL     | 35000      | 2015-01-01
------------------------------------------------
1        |  28      | NULL       | 2015-02-01
------------------------------------------------
1        |  NULL    | 28000      | 2015-03-01
------------------------------------------------
```

I need the result like this.

```
Result
-----------------------------------
UserID   | UserName | Age | Salary
-----------------------------------
1        | foo      | 28  | 28000
-----------------------------------
```

This is just an example. In my real project I have around 6 columns like Age and Salary in above tables.

In table 2 , each record will have only have one value i.e if Age has value then Salary will be NULL and viceversa.

UPDATE :

Table 2 has CreatedDate Column. So i want to get latest "NOTNULL" CELL Value instead of maximum value.

Comment: Do you *really* have data like that in Table 2? If there's anything you can do about it, I'd look at tackling that problem first. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem - will post an answer.

Comment: I hope for same userid you are inserting one information after another. You should try update command

Comment: Mysql of sql server?

Comment: So which now, MySQL or SQL Server? This makes a big difference here.

Comment: SQL server @ThorstenKettner

Comment: Then Ic.'s answer should work for you. Simply replace ID with CreatedDate and see if it works.

Comment: Updated my answer to fit the latest edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: I'm giving you the benefit of the doubt that you know what you're doing, and you just haven't told us everything about your schema.

It looks like `Table 2` is actually an "updates" table, in which each row contains a delta of changes to apply to the base entity in `Table 1`. In which case you can retrieve each column's data with a correlated join (technically an outer-apply) and put the results together. Something like the following:

```
select a.UserID, a.UserName, 
    coalesce(aAge.Age, a.Age),
    coalesce(aSalary.Salary, a.Salary)
from [Table 1] a
outer apply (
    select Age
    from [Table 2] x
    where x.UserID = a.UserID 
    and x.Age is not null
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from [Table 2] y
        where x.UserID = y.UserID
        and y.Id > x.Id
        and y.Age is not null
    )
) aAge,
outer apply (
    select Salary
    from [Table 2] x
    where x.UserID = a.UserID 
    and x.Salary is not null
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from [Table 2] y
        where x.UserID = y.UserID
        and y.Id > x.Id
        and y.Salary is not null
    )
) aSalary
```

Do note I am assuming you have at minimum an `Id` column in `Table 2` which is monotonically increasing with each insert. If you have a "change time" column, use this instead to get the latest row, as it is better.

Comment: This is the only answer so far that tries to make sense of the given data.

Comment: Excellent its working. Thanks @Ic. Instead of just copying the above answer and using , i want to learn this concept . So name of this concept please ? and a question . why the line `and x.Salary is not null` ? with out that line we can use only one outer apply for as many columns we need .

Comment: @JSantosh I'm glad this helped. I'm not exactly sure the technical name of the concept, but you could call your `Table 2` a "changes table". I wouldn't call it a full "history" or "log" table, because it only contains the delta of changed properties and not a full snapshot of the row at the time of update, but the concept is rather similar - keeping track of all versions of an entity over time. The reason we have to do `and x.Salary is not null` is that `null` is a special value meaning "no change", which we need to remove from the result set independently for *each* property.

Answer (score 4):

You can get this done using a simple `MAX()` and `GROUP BY`:

```
select t1.userid,t1.username, MAX(t2.Age) as Age, MAX(t2.Salary) as Salary
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2 on t1.userid=t2.userid
group by t1.userid,t1.username
```

Result:

```
userid  username    Age   Salary
--------------------------------
1       foo         28    35000
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49d549/1)

Answer (score 2):

To get the latest value based on `CreatedDate`, you can use `ROW_NUMBER` to filter for latest rows. Here the partition is based `UserID` and the other columns, `Age` and `Salary`.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8275c/1/0)

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT
        UserID,
        Age = MAX(Age),
        Salary = MAX(Salary)
    FROM(
        SELECT *, Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                        PARTITION BY 
                            UserID, 
                            CASE 
                                WHEN Age IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                                WHEN  Salary IS NOT NULL THEN 2
                            END
                        ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
                        )
        FROM Table2
    )t
    WHERE Rn = 1
    GROUP BY UserID
)
SELECT
    t.UserID,
    t.UserName,
    Age = ISNULL(c.Age, t.Age),
    Salary = ISNULL(c.Salary, t.Salary)
FROM Table1 t
LEFT JOIN Cte c
    ON t.UserID = c.UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

following query should work(working fine in MSSQL) :

```
select a.userID,a.username,b.age,b.sal from <table1> a
inner join 
(select userID,MAX(age) age,MAX(sal) sal from <table2> group by userID) b
on a.userID=b.userID
```